# why does files (nautilus) open a new window although there's one already open?

Tags: 13.10, nautilus, launcher

When I click on "files" in the launcher it opens another window although the normal action is to maximize the window already open. It doesn't always do that. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just place your mouse on the "files" icon then scroll. It maximize your window!

Comment: TOTALLY SOLVES IT!!!!! Finally a decent workaround for this awful bug! thanks alottttttttttt :)))

Answer (score 4):

The same happens to me. It is a confirmed bug.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1170647