# Nautilus opens a new window

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10

Every time I mount any external hard drive or other partitions and open it in nautilus, clicking on the nautilus icon again opens a new window. Can I stop this from happening? If not, is there any workaround for this because its kinda annoying. Also, there is no way to switch back to the old window apart from doing Alt+Tab.

Comment: Use the wheel on the icon.

Comment: What I meant to ask was, can I disable this feature altogether or is it a bug? I just want to maximize the opened window instead of a new one opening.

Comment: @zack [It is a bug.](http://askubuntu.com/a/390527/22949) ([Bug 1170647](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1170647).)